# Open url without using browser in android

Tags: android

I want to create android application which will open url in same application as like facebook application without any browser.
I tried using WebView but it opens the url in browser.

Comment: Implement webViewClient for this

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a webViewClient for your webView.

**Sample code :**

```
 this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }
    });
```